# Case-Sensitive LDAP Queries

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am doing an LDAP query with DirectoryEntry/DirectorySearcher to authenticate a user in Active Directory via a C# web app like so (the ConnectionString property is just equivalent to LDAP://server.domain):

```
internal bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        return false;

    var entry = new DirectoryEntry(this.ConnectionString, username, password);
    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher { SearchRoot = entry, Filter = "(objectclass=user)" };

    try
    {
        var result = searcher.FindOne();
        return true; //connection to AD succeeded, authentication was successful
    }
    catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException)
    {
        return false; //impersonating the user failed
    }
}
```

These queries are all hitting an SBS server which, when you create a new user, appears to use uppercase values for the pre-Windows 2000 (i.e. NetBIOS) name. So, if I add a new user called "Test User", the username might be "tuser" but the NetBIOS name it specifies is "TUser". When a user puts in a user/pass that hits this method, "tuser" fails to be authenticated whereas "TUser" succeeds.

My question is whether it is possible to modify this so usernames don't have to be case-sensitive?

Answer (score 2):

For OpenLDAP there is a syntax to filter values in case-sensitive way.

Two short examples:

```
(&(ou:caseExactMatch:=cwm)(objectClass=person))

+ will match case-sensitive ou= value of 'cwm'
- will NOT match 'CWM', 'CwM' or 'Cwm'

(&(ou=cwm)(objectClass=person))

+ will match case-insensitive (by default) all ou= values like 'cwm', 'CWM', 'CwM', 'Cwm'
```

The syntax seems to be:

```
attr:matchingRule:=value
```

- See "8.3.4 Matching rules" at:
  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/8.2/html/Administration_Guide/Finding_Directory_Entries-LDAP_Search_Filters.html#using-matching-rules
- Also there are several `matchingRule` types:
  https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/MatchingRule

Answer (score 1):

The attribute definition in the schema defines which characters can be used in an attribute value for the attribute being defined. The matching rule(s)  - also in the attribute definition in the schema - determine how attribute values are compared for equality, substring, ordering, and so forth. The matching rule(s) determine the "case-sensitivity" (although it's really not that simple) of a comparison of attributes.

Matching rules must be used by the server (and clients) when comparing attribute values.

Comment: I talked to the person who administers Active Directory for that group (and numerous clients of his own) and he wasn't entirely sure what this comment meant. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: attributes are defined in the schema. attribute definitions contain syntax, matching rules, and some other information. [RFC4517](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4517#section-3.3.5) is the definitive documentation.

Comment: Since this is an SBS server, it is running Exchange which includes OWA. I tried to mimic the login form OWA using the C# code above, but mine is case sensitive whereas OWA isn't. Any guesses as to what the discrepancy is and why OWA works but mine wouldn't?